# How to observe multiple object property changes with rxjs?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, rxjs, observers

I have an object that I want to observe for changes using rxjs.  The object has multiple properties, and when any of them change, I want to be notified of WHICH one was changed and what is its new value.  I've put together the following simplified version of my code but it doesn't work as desired: http://jsbin.com/sidukulowi/1/edit?js,console

```
const store = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  let state = { userActions: {
    window: {
      leftPanelWidth: 300,
      backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
    }
  }};

  observer.next(state);

  state = { userActions: {
    window: {
      leftPanelWidth: 250,
      backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
    }
  }};

  observer.next(state);

  state = { userActions: {
    window: {
      leftPanelWidth: 250,
      backgroundColor: 0xff00ff,
    }
  }};

  observer.next(state);
});


const subscribe = store
  .map( state => state.userActions.window )
  .distinctUntilChanged( ( a, b ) => {
    return a.leftPanelWidth === b.leftPanelWidth && a.backgroundColor === b.backgroundColor
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.dir(val));
```

When the above code runs, I correctly get updates telling me when something in the window object is changed, however I don't know how to figure out which property is the one that changed.

How would I modify this so that I can see that in the first change, it is the `leftPanelWidth` that changed from `300` to `250`, and in the next change it was the `backgroundColor` that changed from `0xffffff` to `0xff00ff` ?

Comment: You can use es6 proxies to setup traps to notify whenever something is changed in the object

Comment: I have no idea what "use es6 proxies to setup traps" means.  Can you point me to a help document or perhaps some sample code showing how to do this?

Comment: Basically proxies help you to setup different types of traps. Traps are essentially just functions which will act as a middleware whenever you try to do some operation on a proxied object (access a property, set a property, delete a property etc). Below articles explains proxies well https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-proxies-in-depth

Comment: I read through that article and this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy but I don't understand how I could use proxies in my situation.  Could you show me some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only just starting to learn RxJX Observable,. So this might not be the simplest solution.

But instead of `distinctUntilChanged`, you could use `pairwise` to check the previous & current values.

eg.

```js
const store = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
  let state = { userActions: {
    window: {
      leftPanelWidth: 300,
      backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
    }
  }};
  
  observer.next(state);
  
  state = { userActions: {
    window: {
      leftPanelWidth: 250,
      backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
    }
  }};
  
  observer.next(state);
  //lets add again to make sure it only when
  //changed..
  observer.next(state); 
  
  state = { userActions: {
    window: {
      leftPanelWidth: 250,
      backgroundColor: 0xff00ff,
    }
  }};
  
  observer.next(state);
  
});


const subscribe = store
  .map(a => a.userActions.window)
  .pairwise()
  .map(([a,b]) => 
    Object.entries(a)
      .filter(([k,v]) => b[k] !== v)
      .map(([k,v]) => ({
        property: k,
        old: a[k],
        new: b[k]
      }))
  )
  .filter(a => a.length)
  .subscribe(val => console.dir(val));

console.log( '--------------Done--------------' );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.8/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: very nice solution!  Now I just have to figure out how to handle the very first call since pairwise will only trigger after the 2nd next call.  Perhaps I could try doing something like next({}) and then next( state ) to see if it kicks off a notification saying the the old = undefined and the new = initial state.